# Oracle DB Developer VM won't talk to internet

Tags: virtualbox

I installed the Oracle VirtualBox Oracle DB Developer pre-packaged VM.  This does boot up, etc.  But there is no network connectivity.  I cannot get to the internet or have the host PC recognize the VM as being on its internal network.

Is there further configuration needed on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to create a Host-only Network to access guest VM's and that you've already configured everything correctly in the OS itself.

1) Ensure that 2 network adapters are configured

- Adapter 1 = Bridged Adapter - NIC name
- Adapter 2 = Host-only Adapter - VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter

2) Make sure the NAT adapters and the Host-only adapter aren't in the same subnetwork. So make it something like Eth0 = 10.1.1.12 & Eth1 = 10.2.1.18

3) Make sure the correct MAC addresses are assigned for each adapter